# How to turn off LCD on camcorder while external microphone is connected?

Tags: canon, camcorder

I'd like to turn off the LCD on my camcorder during recording, to save battery.

However, I cannot close the LCD screen because I have plugged in an external microphone and the external microphone plug is under the LCD (see picture).

I'm using a Canon Vixia HF R42.

[image: Photo from Canon USA]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to turn off the LCD panel when it is open, but you may do two things with it to save your battery:

- *reduce the LCD brightness to the its lowest limit,* and
- *set the LCD Backlight to [L Dim]*

Both commands are available from the `Home Menu -> Other Settings -> Display Setup`.